# Make the LayoutView as Circle while ending the ScaleAnimation in Android?

Tags: java, android, animation

I'm creating an animation in View. After the user click button that become as circle. I'm using Scale animation to archive this. but my view layout radius change after click the button. how can i keep the same radius during the animation or are they anyway to achieve this without libraries ?
[image: img]

> view xml

```
      <View
        android:id="@+id/containerView"
        android:layout_width="363dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="188dp"
        android:background="@drawable/login_boader_round"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.333"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/login_screen_credential_view_holder" />
```

> login_boader_round xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<corners
    android:pivotX="100%"
    android:pivotY="100%"
    android:radius="45dp"

    />
<padding
    android:bottom="0dp"
    android:left="0dp"
    android:right="0dp"
    android:top="0dp" />
<solid android:color="#677FFF" />
<!--<stroke-->
<!--    android:width="3dp"-->
<!--    android:color="#50A4D1" />-->
</shape>
```

> After the button click event

```
public void scaleViewAnimation(View view) {
            ScaleAnimation scaleAnimation = new ScaleAnimation(1f, 0, 1f, 1f, Animation.RESTART, 0.5f, Animation.RESTART, 0.5f);
            scaleAnimation.setDuration(ANIMATION_FADE_DURATION);
            scaleAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
            view.startAnimation(scaleAnimation);
        }
```

Comment: Its better to have two views one is button and other one is Circular Progress bar once you scale down the button you make circular progress bar visible. See if that's works  out for you . There is also some custom view available if you want to check it out just search for `LoadingButtonAndroid`.

Comment: I tried that but after start the animation. the radius of the button will changes. so challenging thing is keep the radius of the view while ending the animation, anyway thank you for your attention 

Comment: have you tried using `MotionLayout` for it it seems like a better way to tackle this .

Comment: I tried ValueAnimator to achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ScaleAnimation` class does not have that property. so i used `ValueAnimator` class to active this. `ANIMATION_TIME` is an integer. you want to give

```
 ValueAnimator anim = ValueAnimator.ofInt(view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight());

        anim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
                int val = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = view.getLayoutParams();
                layoutParams.width = val;
                view.requestLayout();
            }
        });

        anim.setDuration(ANIMATION_TIME);
        anim.start();
```